# rename gradle subproject fails if have another subproject

Tags: gradle

This fails while the other below two scenarios work

```
include 'development'
include 'production'
project(":production").name = "webpiecesexample-prod"
```

This works

```
//include 'development'
include 'production'
project(":production").name = "webpiecesexample-prod"
```

This works but we want to rename the project

```
include 'development'
include 'production'
//project(":production").name = "webpiecesexample-prod"
```

I have no idea why and the error is simply

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':development'.
> Project with path ':production' could not be found in project ':development'.
```

Gradle 7.5

I tried the above 3 scenarios.

Comment: My guess is you're still referencing `:production` in the submodule `:development`, but it is now called `:webpiecesexample-prod`.  In your `build.gradle` for `:development`, do you use the updated name?